# Dockmanager helper for Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, docky

Can I find anywhere a dockmanager helper (for use with DockbarX, docky and awn) for Thunderbird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [add-on available for Thunderbird](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/docky-unread-count/) that allows docks such as docky and awn that use Dbus to display unread mail counts.

[image]

Comment: Thanks unfortunately it does not work with TB 6, even when overriding compatibilitychecks.

Comment: Ok - I've raised this on github - you should update your question to make it clear that thunderbird 6 is your focus.  This answer works for Thunderbird 5.  https://github.com/lpiepiora/docky-thunderbird/issues/9